# Using onclick function on my action link in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("SignUP", "SignUP", "Staff",null, new { @id = "signup",@onclick="return fnSignUP()"})</li>
```

This is my action link in my layout of ASP.NET MVC now instead of going the controller I want to use on click JS function

```
               $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SignUP", "Staff")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(params),
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  success: function (data) {
                     alert(data)
                     $("#dvSignUpModal").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (er) { alert(er.responseText); }
                });
```

this is how I am trying to load the data

`dvSignUpModal` is my div in which I am displaying the data through the AJAX

I tried doing the way I described but I am getting error if i remove the action name

Comment: Could you please format your question.

Comment: At the end of your `fnSignUP`[sic] add `return false;`